# strange xml - read xml by php

Tags: php, xml

for some purposes,I transformed a pptx file to a zip file(test.pptx => test.pptx.zip) and afterwards opened the zip file in order to read some xml by php .

reading one of these xml files through php is being done in a very strange way.

first of all ,I can't read it with simplexml class function `simplexml_load_file($address)`
second I only can read content on it with a function called file_get_contents()
and then when I use var_dump or echo I find my desirable goal "HiGuys" .

How can i get ridoff this file ?

get xml from here   https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zxjo6rggy3m0yx/slide1.xml?dl=0

even i can't write xml in this text !!! ( get inspect element on hiGuys below )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

hiGuys

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, but you seem to be wanting somebody to write a pptx parser for you

Comment: Have you looked at using a library like [PHPPowerPoint](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint) that already knows how to read and write pptx files?

Comment: i only want read this xml and get higuys

Comment: Point #1 simplexml_load_file() is perfectly capable of loading the file correctly, you complain that it can't read it..... what is the actual problem? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Point #2 You need to look through the structure of the XML to find the data you want to extract. To do that, you need to know the structure. You can find the formal specification of that structure [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)